# Custom design push notification like Duolingo

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase with my mobile app and while I used push-notifications before, they seem quite bland and generic. I noticed that, for example, Duolingo sends a custom push notification that stands out (icon, background color, etc). See the image below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTJyv.png)

Could someone kindly point out where or how I can learn more about how to do something similar?

Thanks in advance!

I normally use Firebase Cloud Messaging and it look pretty boring. We can add images, but it looks risky considering the image scaling across different device models.